# Rails - conditional display of html block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On my views I use 1 form that includes a block that renders comments. I do not want to run it when creating a new record. So, I tried conditions like so...

```
<% unless @annotation_id.nil? %>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h4>Comments</h4>
    <%= render @annotation.comments %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
  </div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

This however results in never displaying the block - also when the annotation record exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@annotation_id` is not a record. Are you assigning it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show that you have actually set `@annotation_id` to something.

A simpler way might be to use the `.new_record?` method instead, like:

```
<% unless @annotation.new_record? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if @annotation.persisted?` or `unless @annotation.new_record?`